# Python construct datetime having weekday with other time parameters

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, weekday

I need to construct datetime object from different parameters. For example, I get these parameters:

- integer number from 0 to 6. This one indicates weekday.
- hour and minutes in float format (from 0.0 to 24.0).

And then I know which week of the current year it is going to be. So, for example, let say that datetime should be from `2014-07-18 00:00:00` to `2014-07-24 23:59:00` (seconds can be ignored and left at `00`). So to get exact datetime I need to use above defined parameters.

Let say I would get these parameters `4` (meaning Friday), and `9.5` (meaning `09:30`).

So by doing such construction, I should get a date that would be: `2014-07-22 09:30:00`. How could accomplish such thing?

Do I need to somehow get for example day of the month by knowing which is the week of the year and which weekday it is?

P.S. A bit more detailed example of what I'm trying to accomplish

```
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.today() #using this to get the week I'll be working with.

today = today.replace(day=?) #how to get which day I 
#need to enter by having weekday and knowing that week is the present one?
```

Comment: What week should be used? A weekday plus time is not enough info to get a specific date; it could be *any* date from the subset of all fridays in history.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Look at example after `P.S.`. The week I get by knowing it is this week. So I just get today datetime. And then I can get which week is today. SO I actually need to replace day, hour and minutes by having another mentioned parameters. For hour and minutes it is quite easy to replace by having float number representing time, but how can I replace day, when I have weekday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a starting date, use the relative value of the [`datetime.datetime.weekday()` value](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.weekday) to construct a `timedelta()` object that'll put you onto the right weekday, then replace the hour and minutes:

```
from datetime import timedelta

def relative_date(reference, weekday, timevalue):
    hour, minute = divmod(timevalue, 1)
    minute *= 60
    days = reference.weekday() - weekday
    return (reference - timedelta(days=days)).replace(
        hour=int(hour), minute=int(minute), second=0, microsecond=0)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta, datetime
>>> def relative_date(reference, weekday, timevalue):
...     hour, minute = divmod(timevalue, 1)
...     minute *= 60
...     days = reference.weekday() - weekday
...     return (reference - timedelta(days=days)).replace(
...         hour=int(hour), minute=int(minute), second=0, microsecond=0)
... 
>>> relative_date(datetime.now(), 4, 9.5)
datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 22, 9, 30)
>>> relative_date(datetime.now() - timedelta(days=30), 6, 11.75)
datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 27, 11, 45)
```

Comment: I get error: `AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'replace'`

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like that, if your parameters are weekday and t (time):

```
from datetime import timedelta
monday = today - timedelta(days=today.weekday())
result = (monday + timedelta(days=weekday)).replace(hour=int(t), minutes=int((t - int(t)) * 60))
```

Comment: I actually don't know month of the day. I only know weekday.

Comment: Ah sorry I meant weekday, not day. I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

I would use timedelta to add the difference between weekdays to the datetime

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

friday = 4

today = datetime.now()

friday_this_week = today + timedelta(friday - today.weekday())
```

In your case just replace today with a date that is in the week you want.